# Can't access data downloaded by sklearn.datasets fetch_openml

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently learning ML from the book [Hands-On Machine Learning](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hands-On+Machine+Learning&si=AEcPFx71Yi7YECiZ82vRWCw7NKNJtY_5vrlqqSgfHeUNBju2vGbr9AAFlMXi2VhFki3ZivZvojKElKcNwKofBUR4m4nMFTQzitTrP6zSB0qU0cLNzzBQwVwZUBqh8pyKy1I3_9sQpw7rqg_VD72dvUXlGBpRcr7g6m5LLpJ8eQVGU1tVulO6c2Bo0m7Lt9C5ULh2ZWHXzBq0pCJBDsR6nujAzlMv7u1lSUICiJrdu9V40nd1bLV68rIJfYaUg3sxQ0n1Lo0_bhoI&ictx=1&ved=2ahUKEwjqh9ixgbb9AhXP_SoKHUUcDA8QnZMFegQIYRAC)
 and I'm on the third chapter.

In the start it says to download the MNIST dataset with this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
```

And when i try to access the data it throws at me this error:

```
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X[0]
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 5
      3 y.shape
      4 X.keys()
----> 5 X[0]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3807, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3805 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3806     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3807 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3808 if is_integer(indexer):
   3809     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3804, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:
-> 3804     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805 except TypeError:
   3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

What do I do and why I can't access this like a normal list? Or may be the book doesn't has the correct information since this isn't the first time I get an error after runing exact code as from the book.

I tried to look into the data structure, maybe it wasn't a list after all:

```
X.keys()
X
```

But it is just an ordinary list. Also I'm using jupyter notebook, so I don't write print() or anything to display information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` and `y` are not lists, they are pandas dataframes:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

type(X)
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(y)
# pandas.core.series.Series
```

So, to get the first element of `X`, `X[0]` will indeed produce the error you describe - you need:

```
X.iloc[0]
# result:

pixel1      0.0
pixel2      0.0
pixel3      0.0
pixel4      0.0
pixel5      0.0
           ... 
pixel780    0.0
pixel781    0.0
pixel782    0.0
pixel783    0.0
pixel784    0.0
Name: 0, Length: 784, dtype: float64
```

and similarly

```
y.iloc[0]
# '5'
```

Despite what is claimed in the other answer here (now deleted), omitting `version=1` will not result in any behavior different from the one you describe (i.e. an error when asking for `X[0]`).